# TypeError: setIsEnabled is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm in the process of merging two different next.js projects to create a site that can utilize the cardano wallet 'Nami'. While the code for accessing the wallet works in it's own project, moving the code over brings about some errors that I assume stem from the difference in react versions. Most of the package versions are fairly close if they were shared between the two but from the working Nami project the typescript version is 17.x.x while the in progress build is 18.x.x. That being said I'm getting the error "TypeError: setIsEnabled is not a function" on line 14 when the below code is ran in this new build, but the same code runs fine in the other project. Wondering what's going wrong and any tips for integration would be greatly appreciated!

nami-button-client.tsx

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNamiWalletContext } from './context/nami-wallet'
import styles from '/styles/Home.module.css'
import { Button } from './button'
import client from './client'
import { useCallback } from 'react'

export const NamiButton = () => {
  const { wallet, isEnabled, setIsEnabled } = useNamiWalletContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    wallet
      ? wallet?.isEnabled().then((enabled: boolean) => setIsEnabled(enabled))
      : setIsEnabled(false)
  }, [isEnabled, setIsEnabled, wallet])

  const login = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!wallet) return
    const res = await client.login(wallet)
    console.log(res)
  }, [wallet])

  const enable = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!wallet) return
    await wallet.enable()
  }, [wallet])

  return (
    <>
      {wallet ? (
        isEnabled ? (
          <Button className={styles.button} text={'Login'} onClick={login} />
        ) : (
          <Button className={styles.button} onClick={enable} text={'Enable Nami Wallet'} />
        )
      ) : (
        'Please install nami wallet'
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

I've also included the file that contains 'NamiWalletContext' and 'Wallet'

nami-wallet.tsx

```js
import React, { useContext, createContext, FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

enum Network {
  TESTNET = 0,
  MAINNET = 1,
}

export type Wallet = {
  enable: () => Promise<boolean>
  isEnabled: () => Promise<boolean>
  getBalance: () => Promise<string>
  getNetworkId: () => Promise<Network>
  signTx: (encodedTx: string) => Promise<string>
  getUsedAddresses: () => Promise<string[]>
  getUtxos: () => Promise<string[]>
  submitTx: (encodedSignedTx: string) => Promise<string>
  onAccountChange: (_: () => Promise<void>) => Promise<void>
  signData: (encodedAddress: string, message: string) => Promise<string>
}

type NamiWalletContext = {
  wallet?: Wallet
  useWallet: () => Wallet | undefined
  setWallet: (wallet: Wallet) => void
  address?: string
  setAddress: (address: string) => void
  isEnabled: boolean
  setIsEnabled: (isEnabled: boolean) => void
  checkConnection: () => void
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    cardano?: Wallet
  }
}

const decodeAddress = (str: string) => str

export const NamiWalletContext = createContext({} as NamiWalletContext)

type UseNamiWalletContext = () => NamiWalletContext

export const useNamiWalletContext: UseNamiWalletContext = () => useContext(NamiWalletContext)

export const NamiWalletContextProvider: FC = (children) => {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState<string>('')
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false)
  const [wallet, setWallet] = useState<Wallet>()

  const checkConnection = async () => {
    if (window.cardano && (await window.cardano.isEnabled())) {
      const encodedAddress = (await window.cardano.getUsedAddresses())[0]
      const address = decodeAddress(encodedAddress)
      setAddress(address)
      setIsEnabled(!!address)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isEnabled) {
      window?.cardano?.onAccountChange(async () => {
        const addresses = await window.cardano?.getUsedAddresses()
        const encodedAddress = addresses ? addresses[0] : 'Cant load wallet address'
        const address = decodeAddress(encodedAddress)
        setAddress(address)
        setIsEnabled(!!address)
      })
    }
  }, [isEnabled])

  useEffect(() => {
    checkConnection()
  }, [isEnabled, wallet])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.cardano ? setWallet(window.cardano) : setTimeout(() => setWallet(window.cardano), 300)
  }, [])

  const useWallet = () => window.cardano

  return (
    <NamiWalletContext.Provider
      value={{
        wallet,
        useWallet,
        setWallet,
        address,
        setAddress,
        isEnabled,
        setIsEnabled,
        checkConnection,
      }}
    >
      (children)
    </NamiWalletContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: What does the `useNamiWalletContext` returns?

Comment: Is the `NamiButton` component wrapped by `NamiWalletContextProvider` anywhere up its parent components? You need to wrap it with the provider or your context won't be available.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your import at the top of the code snippit, it looks like the functionality of the `useNamiWalletContext` function is custom.

`import { useNamiWalletContext } from './context/nami-wallet'`

If you navigate to the `/context/nami-wallet` path in your project directory, you should find the implementation of the `useNamiWalletContext` function. The implementation of this function would dictate what is being returned, and therefore what is being populated in your destructured assignment:

`const { wallet, isEnabled, setIsEnabled } = useNamiWalletContext()`

Since this line is using object destructuring, the `useNamiWalletContext` function should be returning an object with at least the following properties like the function below:

```
function useNamiWalletContext() {
  // do some magic stuff here

  return {
    wallet: //some value
    isEnabled: //probably some boolean
    setIsEnabled: //probably supposed to be some function, but isn't
  }
}
```

You'll need to evaluate the innards of the `useNamiWalletContext()` function to determine why it's not returning a function value for `setIsEnabled`.

Comment: This is debugging advice but not an answer to the question. Also, the nami wallet source code is part of the question.

Comment: Hey thanks for the speedy reply, fairly new on stackoverflow here, but I added the file containing the "useNamiWalletContext()" function to the post now as well

Comment: @JacobAnderson, Is the NamiButton component wrapped under the NamiWalletContext Provider?

Comment: @Mackers it is not

Comment: @JacobAnderson, That could be what's happening then. The context object defaults to an empty object if a provider isn't found at some parental level in the component tree. Can you see if the old project had a provider somewhere higher up in the component tree?

Comment: @Mackers I might just be misunderstanding here but isn't it pulling the object context from those first lines
 export const NamiButton = () => {
  const { wallet, isEnabled, setIsEnabled } = useNamiWalletContext()
Where it utilizes "useNamiWalletContext()" to populate "setIsEnabled"
Though I guess this mostly just declares the property as a boolean and sets it to void using react.setstate i believe. Going through it now but I can't find any higher up providers outside of the actual "NamiWalletContextProvider" function

Comment: @JacobAnderson Referring to the useContext docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext
`useContext` will only provide the context coming from the nearest <MyContext.Provider>. In your case, it looks like the provider component is missing as a parent. You should take a look in the old project to see where `NamiWalletContextProvider` is used.

Comment: Additionally, those docs have an example where you can see the `<ThemeContext.Provider>` as a (grand)parent component of `<ThemedButton>`, where the `useContext` function is used.